# Error Code: 1054 : Unknown column 'Orders.Customer_ID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1054

I am constantly getting this Error Even there is not any Syntactical Error shown.

I made two table namely 'Customers' and 'Orders' and when i am trying to use FULL JOIN as given below in mySQL Workbench.

```
SELECT DATE,NAME,Order_Price,Delivery_Address
FROM Orders
FULL JOIN Customers
ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID;
```

Please see the Linked screenshot of my both Table:-

Customer Table

[image]

Orders Table

[image]

It shows the error 1054.

Comment: I don't see a customer_id field in your tables... and both of your screenshots are identical...

Comment: Also MySql does not support full outer join and this should be the error that you would get first.

Comment: @forpas Not quite. 'Full' is a recognised keyword, but it isn't reserved, so in this instance, it's simply interpreted as an alias to orders!

Comment: @zealous Next time you're editing a post, make sure you're not omitting relevant details from the question!

Answer (score 2):

FULL [OUTER] JOIN isn't a thing in MySQL, so your query is instead misinterpreted as follows:

```
SELECT date
     , name
     , order_price
     , delivery_address
  FROM orders full
  JOIN customers 
   ON orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID;
```

...where full is an alias for orders. If you change the last line to...

```
ON full.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID;
```

... it will work; it just won't return the result you desire. But alternatives for FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL are widely discussed elsewhere, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry points out, `full join` is not supports in MySQL.  However, it is probably not at all necessary for your query.  It is hard to imagine orders where the `Customer_Id` is not valid.  You might have customers with no orders, but this should do wha tyo uwant:

```
SELECT DATE, NAME, Order_Price, Delivery_Address  -- you should qualify all column references
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID;
```

If you were in the habit of always using table aliases, then you would find that this query:

```
SELECT DATE, NAME, Order_Price, Delivery_Address  -- you should qualify all column references
FROM Customers c FULL JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID;
```

returns an error.